# Confirmation prompt for thunar before closing all tabs?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar, tabs

I frequently use thunar with multiple tabs, however sometimes I accidentally press Alt+f4 and close the entire window when I only mean to close the tab.

I realize the keybind Ctrl+w only closes the current tab, however pressing Alt+F4 is kind of muscle memory for me so I often find myself using it instead by accident.

This has led to many times where I close the entire window by accident when I mean to only close the current tab. Most other programs that I use (for example firefox) prompt me when I am about to close multiple tabs.

Does any such functionality exist for thunar? If not, does there exist an easy way to extend thunar to add such a functionality? It is my preferred file manager since it is so fast and lightweight so I'd rather not switch to anther.